# Linq query to get the distinct values for repeated id's in a list

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose this is my member class

```
class Member 
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }
}
```

And, this is list.

```
var list = new List<Member>();
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName = "andy", Distance = 3 });
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "02", MemberName = "john", Distance = 5 });
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName = "mathew", Distance = 7 });
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "03", MemberName = "bakara", Distance = 2 });
```

Can anyone please suggest the logic/ linq query to get the List having distinct/unique categoryID with respective MemberNames separated with comma

The output should be :

```
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName="andy,mathew"});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "02", MemberName="john"});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "03", MemberName="bakara"});
```

Comment: You can combine group by `CategoryId` and `string.Join`

Comment: can you give me any code how to do that

Comment: Perhaps your `Member`s should actually be stored in a `HashSet<CategoryId, Member>`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by `CategoryId` and then join the `MemberName` values for each group like this:

```
var result =
    list.GroupBy(member => member.CategoryId)
    .Select(group => new //Do you want an anonymous type or a Member object?
    {
        CategoryId = group.Key,
        MemberName = string.Join(",", group.Select(member => member.MemberName))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @MaciejLos, why? OP wants the result to be in a list.

Comment: Why? OP doesn't explain what he want to achieve. Till there's no need to change collection/list, i'd suggest to use IEnumerable. Take a look here: http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/

Comment: One reason to invoke `ToList` (or `ToArray`) is to make sure that the LINQ query is executed only once. If you don't invoke `ToList` and then use the enumerable more than one time, then the query will be executed more than one time.

Comment: I understand your point of view, Yacoub. Is there any reason to use it together with anonymous type?

Comment: What is the difference if it was an anonymous type based list?